# Kafka10 consumer (Re-)joining group

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a topic with 40 Partitions and planning to run consumers with 10 consumer in each VM( totally 4 VM).

When I start a process with 10 consumers in a 4 core VM, it works as expected.  But, when I start with 10 consumers in a 2 core VM, i keep getting the below info and it stucks there. It is not even consuming a single message.

```
INFO  : loggerName="o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator" threadName="group1" txnId="" Revoking previously assigned partitions [topic1] for group group1
INFO  : loggerName="o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator" threadName="default-dispatcher-9" txnId="" (Re-)joining group group1
```

But this works fine with 5 consumers in 2 core machine.

Thanks

Comment: The logs mean the group is experiencing a rebalance which often takes quite a long time if there are many partitions and consumer instances. The logs itself show no obvious exceptions.

Comment: We dont see any rebalance for this consumer in the broker side. Also, it is working fine with 4 core VM

Comment: It might because of the fact that that broker is not the coordinator for the group.

Comment: I dont understand. One of the broker( 3 node cluster ) is expected to be a coordinator of the group. Any reason, why it is not?